# Java Component Type of 2D Array

Tags: java

I have a 2D array `int[][] myArray` populated with integers.

If I do `myArray.getClass().getComponentType()`, it returns me `[I`.

Why is that so?

**Edit**
I have another library to check the component type of my 2d array. It only allows `Integer.TYPE`, `Character.TYPE`, `Long.TYPE` and so on.
Or, does it mean that with this check, it does not allow me to use 2D array at all?

Comment: `[I` is the name of `int[].class`

Comment: Are you trying to get `int.class`?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to get ```Integer```. Believe I should just convert it to ```Integer[][]```?

Comment: If you can do that, then yes. But if you can do that. can't you just say `Integer.class` directly?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more completely what it is you need to do or need to know?

Comment: @Sweeper I just tried Integer[][], it returned me ```[Ljava.lang.Integer```. Is there a way for me to get ```Integer``` out of this 2D array? Because I have another Library to check the component type of my array. It only allows ```Integer.TYPE```.

Comment: @xzk Umm... But `Integer.TYPE` is `int.class`, not `Integer.class`.

Comment: @Sweeper I see. Then how should I change my 2D array so that I can get ```int.class```?

Comment: @Steve I have edited my post. Appreciate if you could help. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive method:

```
private static Class<?> getComponentTypeOfMultidimensionalArray(Class<?> arrayType) {
    if (arrayType.isArray()) {
        return getComponentTypeOfMultidimensionalArray(arrayType.getComponentType());
    } else {
        return arrayType;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(getComponentTypeOfMultidimensionalArray(int[][].class)); // int
```

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer. However, I am unable to change how the library checks my component type. The library always just do ```value.getClass().getComponentType()```, where ```value``` is my array. I accept your answer because I will take that I am not allowed to use 2D array with this library then. I think I need to change my algorithm :)

Comment: @xzk Then you can only give your library 1D arrays :-( The disadvantage of depending on someone else, isn't it? If the library is open source, try submitting a PR.

Answer (score 2):

The `getComponentType()` method of `java.lang.Class class` is used to get the Class representing the component type of an array, if this class represents one. Else it returns null.

The `getClass()` is the method of Object class. This method returns the runtime class of this object.

For 1D array , for example : `int arr[] = new int[5]`, when we try to get class,`arr.getClass()` ,the output is

> class [I

Again for same 1D array, when we try `arr.getClass().getComponentType()`, the output is

> int

A 2D array can be called as an array of an array.

For 2D array , for example : `int arr[][] = new int[5][5]`, when we try to get class,`arr.getClass()` ,the output is

> class [[I

**Explanation :class [ => represents array [ => represents array I => represents Integer**

for `float arr[][]`, it would be

> class [[F

When we try `arr.getClass().getComponentType()`, the output is

> class [I

When we again try to getComponetType() , i.e. `Arr.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType()`, we get output as

> int

From the above results, it is clearly seen that, for N-dimensional array we have to repeatedly Get Component Type until we unwrap the class Type

Comment: Great sharing! Thank you!

Comment: Always Welcome!@xzk

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to understand Sweeper's answer better.